# Expected ',' separator and unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked for a solution on these errors for a day now, and i have no idea how to solve them. The code below receives multiple error messages:

> Use of unresolved identifier NSCalendarUnitDay

on line:

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay
```

And three errors:

> - Expected ',' separator
> - Use of unresolved identifier 'sharedApplication'
> - use of unresolved identifier 'applicationBadgeNumber'

On line:

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
```

This is the whole code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
    localNotification.alertBody = nil;
    localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay

    //Add one to the icon badge number

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: Well, the code is still half Objective-C.

Comment: Copy & pasting from Objective-C code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]`?

Comment: Any idea how i can rewrite it or where i can read about how it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very basic. You can change code to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
    localNotification.alertBody = nil;
    localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

    //Add one to the icon badge number

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happen because you try to execute Objective-C code in Swift.

Just replace that line with

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
```

When you see something like this `[ClassName classMethod]` or this `*variable` or something similar it is Objective-C. And `[]` means that you send message to object. In Swift you simply call method with `()`: `ClassName.classMethod()`